# Update SQL table with cases

Tags: mysql, sql-update, set, case

I have a table and I want to update a specific columns by taking into account some conditions. For example the **var1** will get different value depending on the **columnC** field. I am using the code below and I get no error on MySQL Workbench, but I have 0 rows affected. The **var1** does not change when I run the script.

```
update table
  set number = columnA * columnB,
      var1 = case
              when lower(columnC) like '%aaa%' then var1 =  number
              when lower(columnC) like '%bbb%' then var1 =  number * 2
              when lower(columnC) like '%ccc%' then var1 =  number * 4
              else lower(columnC) 
              end,
      var2 = number / var1
;
```

I tried doing it for every case separately with different updates.

```
update table 
set number = columnA * columnB;
```

*Which works fine.*

```
update table 
set var1 = number where lower(columnC) like 'aaa';
```

*Which does not work at all. The column is not affected. I also tried removing the 'lower' or putting a specific field.value instead of a variable but with no success*

Comment: `then number` and so on directly,no need for var=number

Comment: What data is in the table at present? What is the table schema? Why are you using `LIKE` with no wildcards - you *should* be able to use `=` for the same result.

Comment: Also `like 'aaa'` is translated into `='aaa'` so you probably need wildcards,`like '%aaa%';`

Comment: For the `else`, I think you mean `var1`.

Comment: @Mihai I had this with wildcards.

Comment: @Mihai It works for the 'then number'. I deleted the 'var' from the code there. I am testing it now.

Comment: Show some samle data for columnc I suspect empty space

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query has several obvious issues.  First is the `else` clause.

Second, you have `=` in the `case`.  This is a boolean comparison and will return 0 or 1.

However, the issue may be that you expect the `set` clauses to be executed "sequentially".  That is, you expect `number` to be calculated in the first, then `var1` can use that number, and so on.  But that is not how `update` works (in either MySQL or other databases).  The values on the left come from the "old" record.  The values on the right are set in the "new" record.

So:

```
update table
  set number = columnA * columnB,
      var1 = columnA * columnB *
             (case when lower(columnC) like '%aaa%' then 1
                   when lower(columnC) like '%bbb%' then 2
                   when lower(columnC) like '%ccc%' 4
                   else 1
              end),
      var2 = number / var1
      var2 = (case when lower(columnC) like '%aaa%' then 1/1.0
                   when lower(columnC) like '%bbb%' then 1/2.0
                   when lower(columnC) like '%ccc%' 1/4.0
                   else 1.0
              end);
```

I'm not sure what the `else` clause should be.  I just made it the same as the "aaa" option.

Comment: It works fine now :
update table
  set number = columnA * columnB,
      var1 = case
              when lower(columnC) like '%aaa%' then number
              when lower(columnC) like '%bbb%' then number * 2
              when lower(columnC) like '%ccc%' then number * 4
              else var1 
              end,
      var2 = number / var1
;